# form:select unable to retrieve data from database

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

In my current spring project, when I run the application and open a view with the code below:

```
<form:select path="${entry.key}" class="form-control">
    <c:forEach var="option" items="${values[entry.key]}">
        <form:option value="${option.id}" label="${option.nome}" class="form-control"/>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

or

```
<c:forEach var="option" items="${values[entry.key]}">
    <form:checkbox path="${entry.key}" value="${option.id}" label="${option.nome}" class="form-control"/>
</c:forEach>
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.enums.LabeledEnum
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.isOptionSelected(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.renderFromValue(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.renderFromValue(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:40)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag.writeTagDetails(CheckboxTag.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag.writeTagContent(CheckboxTag.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.private_.cadastrar_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fcheckbox_005f0(cadastrar_jsp.java:936)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.private_.cadastrar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f3(cadastrar_jsp.java:895)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.private_.cadastrar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f4(cadastrar_jsp.java:857)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.private_.cadastrar_jsp._jspService(cadastrar_jsp.java:304)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

related to a possible library I am need add to my project. My `pom.xml` is this:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Anyone can tell me what library I should add to my dependencies to allow me solve this error?

**UPDATE**

Following sugestions, I add to my pom.xml the dependency spring-core. First I add the version 4.0.6, which don't solve my problem. If I try add the version 3.2.9, I can't even build the application due to conflicts of version with the others libraries added in my application.

Because this, I am now searching for a solution to use the tag `form:select` (and the `form:checkbox`, which it's causing the same error) with the version of spring I am using. Below there is some code related to this issue:

- Pagina.java -> one of the entities classes which depends from this tag to data input.
- cadastra.jsp -> renderized html code for the view where the data input takes place.
- getListaAtributos -> method from my service class where the Map `values` used in the code abode is generated.

**Pagina.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pagina")
public class Pagina {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome", unique=true)
    @Order(value=1)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "titulo")
    @Order(value=2)
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name="resumo", length=140)
    @Order(value=3)
    private String resumo;

    @Column(name = "descricao", length=65535)
    @Order(value=4)
    private String descricao;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @Order(value=5)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_page")
    private Pagina pagina;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_product")
    @Order(value=6)
    private Produto produto;
}
```

**cadastra.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <title>Cadastrar Pagina</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="command" class="form" action="/loja/Pagina/cadastra" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                              <label for="titulo">titulo</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <input id="titulo" name="titulo" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                              <label for="resumo">resumo</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <input id="resumo" name="resumo" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                              <label for="nome">nome</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <input id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                              <label for="descricao">descricao</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <textarea id="descricao" name="descricao" class="form-control"></textarea>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">produto</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <select id="produto" name="produto" class="form-control">

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">pagina</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <select id="pagina" name="pagina" class="form-control">

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">imagem da capa (jpeg, 1280x250)</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input type="file" name="picture" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">cadastrar</button>
        </p>

        <div id="yes" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;">
          <strong>Pagina</strong> cadastro efetuado com sucesso! 
        </div>

        <div id="image" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="display: none;">
          <strong>Pagina</strong> cadastro efetuado com sucesso, mas nenhuma imagem foi salva.
        </div>

        <div id="icone" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="display: none;">
          <strong>Pagina</strong> cadastro efetuado com sucesso, mas nenhum &iacute;cone foi salvo.
        </div>

        <div id="all" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="display: none;">
          <strong>Pagina</strong> cadastro efetuado com sucesso, mas nenhuma imagem ou &iacute;cone foram salvos.
        </div>

        <div id="not" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
          <strong>Pagina</strong> n*atilde;o foi possivel efetuar o cadastro. 
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form.form').ajaxForm(function(data) {
            $("#"+data).css("display", "block");
            $('form.form').each(function(){
                this.reset();
            });
            $("#"+data).fadeOut(5000);
        });
        $("input[name='senha']").on("change", function() {
            var senha = $(this).val();
            var senha_md5 = hex_md5(senha);
            $("input[name='senha']").val(senha_md5);
        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**getListaAtributos()**

```
public Map<String, List<String>> getListaAtributos() {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> lista = this.getAtributos();

    for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++)
    {
        Class<?> clazz;
        try {
            String class_name = "com.spring.loja.model."+lista.get(i).toLowerCase()+".persistence.model."+capitalize(lista.get(i));
            clazz = Class.forName(class_name);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            clazz = null;
        }

        if(clazz != null) {
            Field[] campo = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            int max = campo.length;
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int j=0; j<max; j++)
                temp.add(campo[j].getName());

            map.put(lista.get(i), temp);
        } else {
            map.put(lista.get(i), null);
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

Comment: don't you need jstl-api and jstl-impl in maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Watch your transitive dependencies.** By using information from the question and `mvn dependency:tree`, this is what I get:

```
+- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
|  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
\- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
```

You can see that the older versions of *Spring WS* and *Spring Security* pulled some old *Spring Framework* dependencies as well. I strongly suggest to add `<dependencyManagement>` section to your POM and force those dependencies to be 4.0.3:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web/artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```